# how use Accelerometer in Landscape in iphone/ipad

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

i am working on game in which i want to move CCSprite in direction of accelerometer tilt.i have referred this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/457/intro-to-box2d-with-cocos2d-tutorial-bouncing-balls but i am not clear with it. Please can any one help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this solution. I used same for moving sprite from left to right in landscape game.: [See answer here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/33412/accelerometer-to-move-player-left-and-right/33427#33427)

Only change for landscape mode is use accelerometer y in place of x.

```
-(void) accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration
{   
    if(self.isGamePaused || self.isGameOver)
        return;

    float deceleration = 1.0f, sensitivity = 15.0f, maxVelocity = 450;

    if(sGame.IsIpad)
    {
        sensitivity = 14.0f;
        maxVelocity = 850;
        deceleration = 1.5f;
    }

    // adjust velocity based on current accelerometer acceleration
    //    vel.x = vel.x * deceleration + acceleration.x * sensitivity;

    AppController *app = (AppController*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

    float velocity_x = self.gameActor.velocity.x ;

    self.gameActor.accelVal = ABS(acceleration.y);

    if(app.orient == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
    {
        velocity_x = velocity_x * deceleration + acceleration.y * sensitivity;        
    }
    else 
    {
        velocity_x = velocity_x * deceleration + (-acceleration.y) * sensitivity;
    }

    //limit the maximum velocity of the player sprite, in both directions (positive & negative values)
    velocity_x = fmaxf(fminf(velocity_x, maxVelocity), -maxVelocity);

    self.gameActor.velocity  = ccp(velocity_x, self.gameActor.velocity.y);

}
```